# Linear map $f:V\rightarrow V$ injective $\Longleftrightarrow$ surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

Maybe I am not good at looking for the right questions but I haven't seen this task anywhere so I hope it is no duplicate.

I have to prove the following statement:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $f:V \rightarrow V$ a linear map. Show that $f$ is injective $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f$ is surjective.

The following is already known:

$(i)$ $\ker f$ and $\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}\Im f$ are linear subspaces
$(ii)$ There exists an isomorphism $V/\ker f\rightarrow \Im f$
$(iii)$ If $U\subset V$ is a linear subspace then $\dim V/U=\dim V-\dim U$
$(iv)$ $f$ is injective $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\ker f=\{0\}$

So my approach is the following:

$"\Longrightarrow "$
Let $f:V\rightarrow V$ be injective. Then due to $(iv)$ $\dim\ker f=0$. Hence due to $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ $\dim V/\ker f=\dim V=\dim\Im f$. Since $\dim V=\dim\Im f$ it implies that $f$ is surjective.

$"\Longleftarrow "$
Let $f$ be surjective. Then $\dim\Im f=\dim V$. Additionally, because of $(ii)$ it is $\dim\Im f=\dim V/\ker f$. Thus $\dim V=\dim V/\ker f=\dim V-\dim\ker f$. This means that $\dim\ker f=0$ and hence $\ker f=\{0\}$ and thus $f:V\rightarrow V$ is injective.

For me it all makes sense but maybe I missed something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385674/let-v-be-a-k-vector-space-let-fv-to-v-be-a-linear-operator-show-equival

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is correct; personally I like to view it as a corollary of the rank theorem: $\mathrm{dim} \ V=\mathrm{dim \ Im} \ f+\mathrm{dim \ Ker} \ f$ (try to prove it, it is a generalization of your (iii); for the finite dimensional case it is immediate from (ii) and (iii)), which in fact holds for vector spaces of arbitrary dimension.

Comment: so from $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ I know $dimV/Kerf=dim$ $Imf=dimV-dimKerf$. Thus $dimV-dimKerf=dim$ $Imf$ $\Longleftrightarrow dimV=dimKerf+dim$ $Imf$. $f$ is injective => $dimKerf=0$ => $dimV=dim$ $Imf$ => f surjective. | $f$ is surjective => $dim$ $Imf=dimV$ => $dimKerf=0$ => $f$ injective?

Comment: Your proof is correct for the *finite* dimensional case (and also the last two sentences are correct), the problem in the infinite dimensional case is that it makes no sense to write $\mathrm{dim} \ V-\mathrm{dim} \ \mathrm{Ker} \ f$ as both could be infinite! Show that if $(u_i)$ is a basis of the image, $(w_j)$ a basis of the kernel, and $v_i$ with $f(v_i)=u_i$ then $(v_i,w_j)$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: The poster correctly limited the statement of the theorem to the finite-dimensional case.  It’s not true in the infinite dimensional case.  Let $V$ be the space of sequences of the form $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ with finite support (*i.e.*, finitely many non-zero elements) and let $f$ be the function that shifts an entire sequence one that shifts the entire sequence one coordinate to the right.  Then $f$ is injective but not surjective.