# Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space, let $f:V\to V$ be a linear operator, show equivalence between $f$ is injective, surjective and bijective

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some issues understandig a proof of the following theorem.

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space and $f: V \to V$ a
>    linear operator. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is injective
> 2. $f$ is surjective
> 3. $f$ is bijective.

#### Proof

3 => 1, 2:  Trivial

1 => 3:

Let $\dim V = n\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider $\mathscr{B}=\{ b_1,\ldots, b_n\}$ a basis 
for $V$.

Now consider $T = \{ f(b_1), \ldots, f(b_n)\}$. Since $f$ is injective this set is 
linear independent.

If $T$ spans the whole space, then $T$ would be a basis and $f$ would be bijective.

But why does $T$ span the whole space? Lecture notes refer to the following theorem:

> Let $T\subseteq S\subseteq V$ where $T$ is linear independant, $\text{span}(S) =V$ then
>   there exists a basis $\mathscr{B}$ for $V$ such that $T\subseteq \mathscr{B}\subseteq S$.

I don't see how this theorem can be used here.

Comment: How many elements has $T$, and how many elements has a basis?

Comment: Well $n$. So I guess the reasoning is the following? Since $\dim V = n$, each basis of $V$ should have $n$ elements. And since $T$ is linear independant *and* consists of $n$ elements, no elements should be added to make it span the space. Which means it is a basis?

Comment: Right. By the way, do you know the rank formula? [You might know it as the rank-nullity theorem.]

Comment: [Rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) is the standard tool for this kind of statements.

Comment: It's all about "rank" in the next chapter. I'll check it out :)