# Show that any subring $R\subseteq L$ is a field if $K\subseteq L$ is module-finite field extension and $K\subseteq R$..

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, extension-field

This is Exercise 1.50b in Fulton's *Algebraic Curves*.
It's a follow up to showing that algebraic elements form a subfield.
I found similar questions MSE, but with stronger hypothesis.

By module-finite extension we mean that $L$ is finitely-generated as a $K$-module.

**My attempt:**
take $r\in R$ and let $\rho\in L$ be its inverse in the field $L$.
I tried to show that $\rho \in R$, since we know that will happen.

By $K\subset L$ a finitely generated extension we mean that there are $l_1,\dots l_n$ in $L$ such that $r\in R$ can written as $r = l_1k_1+\dots+l_n k_n$.

When $r = l_jk_j$ we have $l_j = rk_j^{-1}\in L$, so $\rho = k_j^{-1}l_j^{-1}\in R$.
This strategy blowed off really hard when the above equation for $r$ had two or more terms.

Comment: I presume $K$ is a field. In that case, let $r\in R$ and consider the elements $1,r,r^2,\ldots$.

Comment: This is false unless $K\subset R$: consider $K=L=\Bbb Q$, $R=\Bbb Z$. If you assume $K\subset R$, then this is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161381/why-does-the-integral-domain-being-trapped-between-a-finite-field-extension-im).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof: Note that since $L$ is a module finite extension of $K$, we have that $L$ is a finite field extension of $K$ which implies that $L$ is algebraic over $K$. Now, let $y \in R$. In particular, $y \in L$ which gives us that $y$ is algebraic over $K$. Let $P(x)=x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots c_{1}x+c_{0}$ be the minimum polynomial for $y$ over $K$. We then have $y^{n} +c_{n-1}y^{n-1} + \dots c_{1}y+c_{0}=0$, which gives $y^{n}+c_{n-1}y^{n-1} + \dots + c_{1}y=-c_{0}$. This implies, $y^{n-1}+c_{n-1}y^{n-2}+ \dots + c_{1} = y^{-1}c_{0}$. Clearly, $y^{-1}c_{0} \in R$ and since $c_{0}^{-1} \in R$, we get $y^{-1} \in R$.